# Swap memory usage high on server

Tags: mail-server

I am observing high swap memory usage on my server host.But I do not see the same memory usage on both of the VMs.

Host memory usage:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           219G        213G        718M        1.3M        5.1G        4.8G
Swap:          8.0G        6.3G        1.7G
```

VM1 memory usage:

```
# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           192G         22G         43G        1.7G        126G        166G
Swap:          2.0G          0B        2.0G
```

VM2 Memory usage:

```
# free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           19G        18G       681M       127M       1.3G       2.5G
-/+ buffers/cache:        15G       4.5G
Swap:         1.0G         0B       1.0G
```

Comment: My swap usually gets used when my main memory is almost full

Answer (score 1):

When you look at memory for your VMs, 192+19 is 211GB. And VM1 is using 126GB for buff/cache. It is typical for linux to eat all the memory which is available to cache i/o. If you want to decrease stress on memory on your host, make VM1 smaller.